# Is there a way to use m17n dhivehi language on elementary?

Tags: language, input

Is there a way to use m17n dhivehi language on elementary ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://wikis.swarthmore.edu/ling073/Dhivehi/Keyboard) looks like what you want.